# Reflexive pronoun vs pronoun

Tags: american-english, british-english, reflexive-pronouns

Which one is correct?

> He engraved photos of himself and his wife on the coins.

Or

> He engraved photos of him and his wife on the coins.

Answer (score 0):

Either is ok, and you would certainly hear both versions in conversation.

Reflexive pronouns like 'himself' are **required** when the subject and the object are the same person. But that is not the case here.

So, you would have to say:

> He marked himself and his wife with an indelible pen.

As @aml mentioned in a comment, my first answer was in fact incorrect. Which just goes to show that a lot of native speakers don't know the rules!

Reflexive pronouns need to be used with objects and indirect objects, and circumstances such as this when "himself and his wife" are objects of a preposition, while 'he' is still subject of the sentence.

It is quite common for people to use the reflexive pronoun, either because they are not sure which pronoun to use ('he' or 'him, and especially 'I' and 'me', which many native speakers struggle with*), or to avoid repeating the pronoun, or to place emphasis on the pronoun.

*Including me apparently.

Comment: No -- **photos** is the *direct* object, but reflexive pronouns should be used for any object (direct, indirect, or object of preposition) that is in the same phrase (not a subordinate, where the subject would change).

Comment: I deleted this answer because I thought it had a mistake in it. I have now hopefully corrected the mistake and restored the answer.

Comment: Quibble: An *indirect object* is the [intended] recipient of an action, marked by the preposition 'to' or 'for' (or the preposition may be omitted if the indirect object is stated before the direct object).  'Of' does not qualify for making an indirect object, so 'himself and his wife' are merely objects of a preposition (in the OP).  I'll upvote if you correct this. (Reflexives are appropriate until the case changes back to *subject*.)

Comment: @aml - assuming you can't edit my post directly, if you want to provide an exact form of words to correct the error, I will happily add it.

Comment: Sorry - I want *you* to understand: "He" is a subject, and "himself and his wife" are objects of a preposition in the OP (and direct objects in your sentence with "pen") -- there are no indirect objects in any of the examples.

Comment: Haha, I do understand, I promise. I was just struggling to find a form of words to put it in that will still explain to the OP in simple terms why we need to use the reflexive form - so I tried to pass the buck!

Comment: @aml Presumably, you mean *this* "of" does not make them indirect objects. "of" does, in *general*, make something an indirect object.